# Triangles generator program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that read from standard input some lines in the format "name;x;y". Each one represents a point in the Cartesian place and I want to print all the triangles that can be generated from them.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    string name;
    double x = 0, y = 0;
};

typedef Point Triangle[3];

vector<Point> ReadPoints();
vector<Triangle> GetTriangles(vector<Point> points);


int main() {
    auto points = ReadPoints();
    auto triangles = GetTriangles(points);

    for (auto beg = triangles.begin(); beg != triangles.end(); ++beg) {
        for (auto bg = begin(*beg); bg != end(*beg); ++bg) {
            cout << bg->name << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}


vector<Point> ReadPoints() {
    vector<Point> points;

    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        istringstream record(line);
        Point pn;
        
        getline(record, pn.name, ';');
        
        string xy;
        getline(record, xy, ';');
        pn.x = stod(xy);

        getline(record, xy, ';');
        pn.y = stod(xy);

        points.push_back(pn);
    }

    return points;
}

vector<Triangle> GetTriangles(vector<Point> points) {
    vector<Triangle> triangles;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size()-2; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < points.size()-1; ++j)
            for (int k = j+1; k < points.size(); ++k)
                triangles.emplace_back(points[i], points[j], points[k]);

    return triangles;
}
```

I get these errors from the compiler, but I can't understand why:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vhdw.png)

Someone can help me?

Comment: `vector<Triangle> GetTriangless` -- See anything strange about the name of that function?  Is that your real code, or are you trying to type the code into the question (instead of simply copying the exact code from your code editor and pasting it into the question)?

Comment: I copy-pasted my code from the editor and translated function and variable name in english. "GetTriangless" is just a typo: in the original version, with correct names, the code doen't work.

Comment: `"GetTriangless" is just a typo:` -- You should ensure that what you are pasting is the exact code you are compiling.  Otherwise, those typos will be copied by us, we compile it, and we get totally different set of compiler errors that you're getting.

Comment: I corrected the code now. I’m sorry

Comment: `Point[3]` does not provide the functions that would allow it to be used as type parameter for vector (unless you specify a custom allocator). I recommending replacing the typedef with `using Triangle = std::array<Point, 3>;` to fix this. You'll need to rewrite the `emplace_back` line a bit to the move constructor though...